# Lazy dependencies on a multi-project Maven project

Tags: build, maven

We're considering using Maven for a large multi project build, to give you an idea of the size, some of the sub-projects have several million lines of code.

The ideal structure would be something like:

- projectA

  - module1
  - module2
- projectB

  - moduleAlpha (depends on moduleBeta)
  - moduleBeta  (depends on projectA:module1)
- ...

Where each module is actually a maven sub-project, and the dependencies are not always at the artifact level (i.e. jars), but rather cause the sub-project to be compiled as necessary.

Adding a common project root allows for expressing the dependencies as described, for example:

- project-root

  - projectA

    - module1
    - module2
  - projectB

    - moduleAlpha (depends on moduleBeta)
    - moduleBeta  (depends on projectA:module1)
  - ...

But forces you to build from project-root. Remember that this is a very large project, and a full build would be something that is not always desirable.

Most teams work at the *projectX* level some even at the *moduleX* level.

What we need is to sometimes build against a generated artifact (that is the jar produced by *module1*), other times we want to build from the source code.

I have taken a look at the reactor plugin, that allows you to resume a build from a certain point or build only the dependents. But it seems very manual (although it is very useful in certain cases).

What I picture is some type artifact repository that builds the artifact when it is required. For example, making *projectA* an artifact repository that *projectB* references.
When you for some reason need a rebuild of *projectA*'s artifact, you could just remove the jar.

Is something like that implemented as part of Maven or as a plugin?
If not, is it feasible to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What we need is to sometimes build against a generated artifact (that is the jar produced by module1), other times we want to build from the source code.

I don't see any particular problem here:

- when you want to build against binary dependencies (jars), just build the artifact you're working on (and let Maven resolve and use binary dependencies)
- when you want to build against source code, use a reactor build and the advanced reactor options, for example to build the dependencies of moduleAlpha and moduleAlpha:

  ```
  mvn -pl moduleAlpha -am
  ```

> What I picture is some type artifact repository that builds the artifact when it is required. For example, making projectA an artifact repository that projectB references. When you for some reason need a rebuild of projectA's artifact, you could just remove the jar.

I'm not sure to understand what you're talking about and *removing JARs* doesn't sound like a good idea.

What you need is a continuous build process that builds the whole project as often as possible to produce SNAPSHOT of all modules and deploy them in a corporate repository. That's just the way to go.

And to make the build as fast as possible, I'd consider using Maven 3.x and the [parallel builds](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/parallel-builds-in-maven-3.html) option.